# select all checkboxes if none are select in php query

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a script wher users can find exercise from a database, I have checkboxes for the user to find specific exercises the script works fine when a least 1 checkbox is selected from each checkbox group however I would like it that if no checkboxes was selected then it would the results of all checkboxes.

my checkbox form looks like this

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="criteria">
    <p><strong>MUSCLE GROUP</strong></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="muscle[]" id="abdominals" value="abdominals"/>Abdominals<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="muscle[]" id="biceps" value="biceps" />Biceps<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="muscle[]" id="calves" value="calves" />Calves<br />
     ect...
    <br /><p><strong>EQUIPMENT (please select a least one)</strong></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" id="equipment" value="bands"/>Bands<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" id="equipment" value="barbell" />Barbell<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" id="equipment" value="dumbbell" />Dumbbell<br />
     ect....
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Generate Query" />
    </form>
```

and here is my script

```
     <?php

      if(isset($_POST['muscle']) && !empty($_POST['muscle'])){   
if(isset($_POST['equipment']) && !empty($_POST['equipment'])){   

//get the function
 include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/scripts/functions.php');    
 $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
       $limit = 14;
       $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

  // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
       $clean_muscle = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['muscle']);
       $clean_equipment = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['equipment']);

  // Convert the array into a string.
       $muscle = implode("','", $clean_muscle);
       $equipment = implode("','", $clean_equipment);

 $options = array();
       if(array($muscle))
       {
       $options[] = "muscle IN ('$muscle')";
       }
      if(array($equipment))
       {
      $options[] = "equipment IN ('$equipment')";
 }


      $fullsearch = implode(' AND ', $options);

      $statement = "mytable";
      if ($fullsearch <> '') {
      $statement .= " WHERE " . $fullsearch;
      }

     if(!$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}"))
     {
     echo "Cannot parse query";
 }
 elseif(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
 echo "No records found";
 }

else {
echo "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo "".$row['name'] ."</br>           
            ".$row['description'] ."";
        }
    }
         echo "<div class=\"new-pagination\">";
        echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
        echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

Im new with php so my code may not be the best. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.

Comment: so you want to select all checkboxes, if the selection is empty? Or you just want to select the first of each group?

Comment: You could call a validation function before submitting the form. It would loop through the checkboxes, taking their logical OR. This will be FALSE if one were set; you could either pass a new variable "ALL" to the database script, or set all the variables before calling it.

Comment: If no checkbox from the muscle[] group is selected then I would like it to select all checkboxes for the group muscle[] or show show all results, if none are selected in the equipment[] group then all that group checkboxes to be selected

Comment: @Floris how would I call a validation function could you please give me a sample code if possible. Thanks

Comment: It seems your code should _almost_ work as is. Looking at the way you handle the case of no boxes checked, it seems you should have an empty array `$options[]` which should trigger your `if ($fullsearch <> '')` condition to be false, so there should be no `WHERE` added to your query., and you should return everything. Since that is not the case, I would add some debugging statements.

If you add an `echo $statement` line before your mysql_query, what output does it give when you have no boxes selected? And when you do?

Comment: Hi Floris, when I add the echo $statement it does nothing, and when I add the empty array $options[] it seems to be ignored when no checkboxes are selected. I not sure if it has something to do with   if(isset($_POST['muscle']) && !empty($_POST['muscle'])){   
if(isset($_POST['equipment']) && !empty($_POST['equipment'])){   posted at the top of the code.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you confirm whether your code executes - put `echo` statements everywhere, `echo1`, `echo 2` etc. You can then see where code stopped executing, add further debug statements, etc... Unrelated note - add `@` in front of user name so user gets notified that a comment was left for their attention. Needed when you are responding to comment rather than answer.

Comment: @Floris thank you for your response, I added echo statements and it seems to echo everywhere with out any problems, also I added this code to the options array for it to return all results if none are found.     if(!empty($equipment))
  {
  $options[] = "equipmentgroup ='all'";
  }
  if(!empty($muscle))
  {
  $options[] = "musclegroup ='all'";
  }

Comment: So - the code executes all the way through yet the `$statement` is blank? Shouldn't it have `"mytable"` in it?

Comment: @Floris when no checkboxes are checked it does return anything but if one or more check boxes from each group it returns the full statement

Comment: So `$statement` is empty when no boxes are checked yet you say the line that assigns the value of `mytable` got executed? That makes no sense, does it? I will try to replicate the problem later tonight.

Comment: @Floris I cannot make out why it doesn't work. It seems to ignore the code for when the checkbox is empty (unchecked). everything else works perfect, it just has a problem when the checkbox is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I think I have figured it all out. You were right - the main problem was in your `isset` and `isempty` calls.  I created some variations on your file, and this shows what is going on. Note - since I don't have some of your "other" functions, I am only showing what is going wrong in the outer parts of your function.

## Part 1: validating function

In the following code, I have added two JavaScript functions to the input form; these were loosely based on scripts you can find when you google "JavaScript validation checkbox". The `oneBoxSet(groupName)` function will look through all document elements; find the ones of type `checkBox`, see if one of them is checked, and if so, confirms that it belongs to `groupName`. For now, it returns "true" or "false". The calling function, `validateMe(formName)`, runs your validation. It is called by adding

```
onclick="validateMe('criteria'); return false;"
```

to the code of the `submit` button. This basically says "call this function with this parameter to validate the form". In this case the function "fixes" the data and submits; but you could imagine that it returns "false", in which case the submit action will be canceled.

In the `validateMe` function we check whether at least one box is checked in each group; if it is not, then a hidden box in the "all[]" group is set accordingly.

I changed the code a little bit - it calls a different script (`muscle.php`) instead of the `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` you had... obviously the principle is the same.

After this initial code we will look at some stuff I added in `muscle.php` to confirm what your original problem was.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

// go through all checkboxes; see if at least one with name 'groupName' is set
// if so, return true; otherwise return false
function oneBoxSet(groupName)
{
    var c=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
        if (c[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
           if (c[i].checked) {
             if (c[i].name == groupName) {
               return true; // at least one box in this group is checked
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return false; // never found a good checkbox
}

function setAllBoxes(groupName, TF)
{
    // set the 'checked' property of all inputs in this group to 'TF' (true or false)
    var c=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // alert("setting all boxes for " + groupName + " to " + TF);
    for (var i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
        if (c[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if (c[i].name == groupName) {
            c[i].checked = TF;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// this function is run when submit is pressed:
function validateMe(formName) {
  if (oneBoxSet('muscle[]')) {
    document.getElementById("allMuscles").value = "selectedMuscles";
    //alert("muscle OK!");
    } 
  else { 
    document.getElementById("allMuscles").value = "allMuscles";
    // and/or insert code that sets all boxes in this group:
    setAllBoxes('muscle[]', true);
    alert("No muscle group was selected - has been set to ALL");
    }
  if (oneBoxSet('equipment[]')) {
    document.getElementById("allEquipment").value = "selectedEquipment";
    //alert("equipment OK!");
    }
  else  {
    document.getElementById("allEquipment").value = "allEquipment";
    // instead, you could insert code here that sets all boxes in this category to true
    setAllBoxes('equipment[]', true);
    alert("No equipment was selected - has been set to ALL");
    }
  // submit the form - function never returns
  document.forms[formName].submit();  
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="muscle.php" method="post" name="criteria">
        <p><strong>MUSCLE GROUP</strong></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="muscle[]" id="abdominals" value="abdominals"/>Abdominals<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="muscle[]" id="biceps" value="biceps" />Biceps<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="muscle[]" id="calves" value="calves" />Calves<br />
        <input type="hidden"   name="all[]" id="allMuscles" value="selectedMuscles" />
        etc...<br>
        <br /><p><strong>EQUIPMENT (please select a least one)</strong></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" id="equipment" value="bands"/>Bands<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" id="equipment" value="barbell" />Barbell<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" id="equipment" value="dumbbell" />Dumbbell<br />
        <input type="hidden"   name="all[]" id="allEquipment" value="selectedEquipment" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Generate Query" onclick="validateMe('criteria'); return false;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Part 2: what's wrong with the PHP?

Now here is a new start to the php script. It checks the conditions that you were testing at the start of your original script, and demonstrates that you never get past the initial `if` statements if a check box wasn't set in one of the groups. I suggest that you leave these tests out altogether, and instead get inspiration from the code I wrote to fix any issues. For example, you can test whether `equipmentAll` or `muscleAll` were set, and create the appropriate query string accordingly.

```
<?php

    echo 'file was called successfully<br><br>';
    if(isset($_POST['muscle'])) {
       echo "_POST[muscle] is set<br>";
       print_r($_POST[muscle]);
       echo "<br>";

       if (!empty($_POST['muscle'])) {
         echo "_POST[muscle] is not empty!<br>";
         }
         else {
         echo "_POST[muscle] is empty!<br>";
         }
         }
    else {
      echo "_POST[muscle] is not set: it is empty!<br>";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['equipment'])) {
       echo "_POST[equipment] is set<br>";
       print_r($_POST['equipment']);
       echo "<br>";

       if (!empty($_POST['equipment'])) {
         echo "_POST[equipment] is not empty!<br>";
         }
         else {
         echo "_POST[equipment] is empty!<br>";
         }
         }
    else {
      echo "_POST[equipment] is not set: it is empty!<br>";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['all'])) {
      echo "this is what you have to do:<br>";
      print_r($_POST['all']);
      echo "<br>";
      }


//    if(isset($_POST['muscle']) && !empty($_POST['muscle'])){
//        if(isset($_POST['equipment']) && !empty($_POST['equipment'])){
```

If you call this with no check boxes selected, you get two dialogs ('not OK!'), then the following output:

```
file was called successfully

_POST[muscle] is not set: it is empty!
_POST[equipment] is not set: it is empty!  
this is what you have to do:  
Array ( [0] => allMuscles [1] => allEquipment )
```

If you select a couple of boxes in the first group, and none in the second:

```
file was called successfully

_POST[muscle] is set
Array ( [0] => abdominals [1] => calves )
_POST[muscle] is not empty!
_POST[equipment] is not set: it is empty!
this is what you have to do:
Array ( [0] => selectedMuscles [1] => allEquipment )
```

I do not claim to write beautiful code; but I hope this is functional, and gets you out of the fix you were in. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I think you are right and im best to do away with the show all from a group if none are selected. Your script will work much better and user friendly. Really appreciate all your help. Thank you

Comment: Actually you _can_ do show all now. The script catches the empty checkboxes (dialog was just there to show you what can be done), and it sets the hidden variable - so when you create your query, you look at the variable, see what it is, and build the query accordingly. Your original problem was "my script doesn't run when no boxes are selected" - I show in part 2 that this is caused by your choice of `isset` (when no boxes are selected, `isset()` is false...). How you decide to use the building blocks is now up to you. Do you know how to "accept" the answer?

Comment: I have edited my validation solution to include a function that will set all the boxes in a group if none are checked - this means your original php code should then be able to run without modification...

Comment: thanks @Floris but for some reason the javascript is being ingnored with my original php code. I cant see any reason why. any ideas what might be causing it to be ignored

Comment: A typo? Did you run firebug on the JavaScript to look for errors? I had to type my code edit in by hand - an error could have crept in. I will take a look later today.

Comment: It was my mistake - when typing in the new function I used the wrong name. Fixed now - and demo available for your pleasure at http://www.floris.us/SO/muscle1.html

Comment: Thank you so much @Floris, That has got everything working perfect. You have been a great help and I really can't thank you enough. All is working now

Comment: You're welcome. I learned quite a bit from this myself... :-)

Comment: Hi @Floris, I was just wondering the script works great but when I click the next button on the pagination the results show everything and loses the values thayt have been checked,  I think I need to use sessions to store the statement into the pagination but i cant seem to get it to work. Any ideas how I would add sessions or something else so the pagination would store the statement over all the pages

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with your pagination - it involves code you do not show. Why don't you start a new question - putting the working code you have, describing your problem, and the things you have done to make it work. You might then post a link to it in a comment here so I see it.

Comment: Hi @Floris , I have posted the new question with all my code here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126001/how-to-maintain-checkbox-query-through-pagination)

Comment: I see that while I was asleep, you were already getting lots of advice on this next problem... May take a look later if it's not solved by then.