# how to maintain checkbox query through pagination

Tags: php, session, pagination, checkbox

I have a script with the code below and a pagination where the user can check checkboxes to narrow doen the results shown everything seems to work great the only problem is that when a user clicks the next page in the pagination the results are lost and the default results are shown. I think I may need to use sessions to store the query or statement but I am unsure how to use them. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.

Here is my code

```
       <?php


 //get the function
 include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/scripts/function1.php'); 

 $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        $limit = 14;
        $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;     

   if(isset($_POST['muscle'])) {

   // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
         $clean_muscle = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['muscle']);

    // Convert the array into a string.
         $muscle = implode("','", $clean_muscle);


   if (!empty($_POST['muscle'])) {

      $options[] = "muscle IN ('$muscle')";
     } else {
      $options[] = "";
     }
     } else {
      $options[] = "allmuscle = 'all' ";
     }

   if(isset($_POST['equipment'])) {

    // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
   $clean_equipment = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['equipment']);

   // Convert the array into a string.
   $equipment = implode("','", $clean_equipment);

   if (!empty($_POST['equipment'])) {


      $options[] = "equipment IN ('$equipment')";
     } else {
      $options[] = "";
     }
     } else {
      $options[] = "allequipment = 'all'";
     }

   if(isset($_POST['all'])) {
     $options[] = "";
  } 


 $fullsearch = implode(' AND ', $options);


 $statement = "exercise ";

 if ($fullsearch <> '') {
 $statement .= " WHERE " . $fullsearch;
 } else {
 $statement .= "";
 }



 if(!$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  {$statement}  LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}"))
 {
 echo "Cannot parse query";
 }   
 elseif(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
 echo "No records found";
 }  


 else {

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 echo "".$row['name'] ."<br />
              ".$row['description'] ."";
        }
}
         echo "<div class=\"new-pagination\">";
        echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
        echo "</div>";


?>
```

and here is the pagination script

```
     <?php

    function pagination($query, $per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '?'){        
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total = $row['num'];
      $adjacents = "1"; 

    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;   

    $firstPage = 1;
       $prev = ($page == 1)?1:$page - 1; 

    $prev = $page - 1;                          
    $next = $page + 1;
      $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;


    $pagination = "";


    if($lastpage >  1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<ul class=\"pagination1\">";

                if ($page == 1)
    {
    $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">First</a></li>";
     $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">Prev</a></li>"; 
     }
        else
      {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$firstPage\" >First</a></li>";
     $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$prev\" >Prev</a></li>"; 
     }



                $pagination .= "<li class=\"details\">Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))

        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$counter\" >$counter</a></li>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$counter\" >$counter</a></li>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">... </li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$lpm1\" >$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$lastpage\" >$lastpage</a></li>";       
            }
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=1\" >1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=2\" >2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">...</li>";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$counter\" >$counter</a></li>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">..</li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$lpm1\" >$lpm1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$lastpage\" >$lastpage</a></li>";       
            }
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=1\" >1</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=2\" >2</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li class=\"dot\">..</li>";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"current\">$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$counter\" >$counter</a></li>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
            $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$next\">Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"{$url}page=$lastpage\" >Last</a></li>";
        }else{
            $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">Next</a></li>";
            $pagination.= "<li><a class=\"inactive\">Last</a></li>";
        }
        $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
    }


    return $pagination;
} 
?>
```

here is my checkboxes

```
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="criteria">
 <ul>
  <li class="head">
 <input type="checkbox" name="allmuscle[1]" class="remember_cb" id="allMuscles" value="selectedMuscles" >All Muscle Groups<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[2]" class="remember_cb" id="abdominals" value="abdominals"/>Abdominals<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[3]" class="remember_cb" id="biceps" value="biceps"/>Biceps<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[4]" class="remember_cb" id="calves" value="calves"/>Calves<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[5]" class="remember_cb" id="chest" value="chest" />Chest<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[6]" class="remember_cb" id="forearms" value="forearms"/>Foreamrs<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[7]" class="remember_cb" id="glutes" value="glutes"/>Glutes<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[8]" class="remember_cb" id="hamstrings" value="hamstrings"/>Hamstrings<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[9]" class="remember_cb" id="lats" value="lats"/>Lats<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[10]" class="remember_cb" id="lower-back" value="lower-back"/>Lower Back<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[11]" class="remember_cb" id="middle-back" value="middle-back" />Middle Back<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[12]" class="remember_cb" id="neck" value="neck"/>Neck<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[13]" class="remember_cb" id="quadriceps" value="quadriceps" />Quadriceps<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[14]" class="remember_cb" id="shoulders" value="shoulders" />Shoulders<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[15]" class="remember_cb" id="traps" value="traps" />Traps<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="muscle[16]" class="remember_cb" id="triceps" value="triceps"/>Triceps<br /></li>
      </ul>
            <br /><p><strong>EQUIPMENT</strong></p>
     <ul>
   <li class="head"><input type="checkbox" name="allequip[]" class="remember_cb" id="allEquipment" value="selectedEquipment" >All Equipment<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[1]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="bands"/>Bands<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[2]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="barbell" />Barbell<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[3]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="body-only" />Body Only<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[4]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="cable" />Cable<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[5]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="dumbbell" />Dumbbell<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[6]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="ez-curl-bar"/>EZ Curl Bar<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[7]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="exercise-ball"/>Exercise Ball<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[8]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="foam-roll" />Foam Roll<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[9]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="kettlebell" />Kettlebell<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[10]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="machine" />Machine<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[11]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="medicine-ball"/>Medicine Ball<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[12]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="none" />None<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="equipment[13]" class="remember_cb" id="equipment" value="other" />Other<br /></li>
```

The script all works fine my only problem is that once the checkboxes are checked the results are returned but only stay on the first page as soon as you click next or page 2 the results or query are lost.

Comment: if you do not want to save it in session.. you can send the checkbox value as a get variable to the next pagination value (constantly check if the check value isset and if it does use it in your db query)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Dinesh , I dont mind using sessions Im just not sure where or how to place them my code. Also how can send the checkbox value as a get variable to the next pagination value, Im new with php so if you could give me some example it would be a great help.

Comment: the given code does not provide me with more information.. if I believe this is the only code which does all the work of page display and pagination functionality.. than you will also have to provide the html part of the code where to see how actually you implement the checkbox functionality..

Comment: Sorry @Dinesh I forgot the checkboxes, I have updated my code above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For sessions, just store the search parameters to `$_SESSION` array. Don't forget to overwrite the stored parameters when the request comes from the initial search form.

```
$_SESSION['muscle'] = ...
```

Another way without using user session would be to re-post the search parameters in your results list. You could put them in a hidden form element or add manually to the URL of the page forward/backward link:

```
"<form action=\"...\" id=\"page_prev\">".
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"muscle\" value=\"$_POST['muscle']\" .
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"page\" value=\"$prev\";
```

or

```
"<a href=\"{$url}page=$prev&muscle=$_POST['muscle']\"
```

For the form variant you also need some JS code to submit the form as a link to click on:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('page_prev').submit()">Prev</a>;
```

Comment: Thanks @rantanplan I very new with sessions but would prefer to use them, How do I store the search parameters to $_SESSION array, do I set the statement in with sessions if so any chance you can give an example of how to implement the code to the statement.

Comment: See @Denish's answer on how to setting the session and reading from it.

Comment: Hi @Floris , I am still having problems with getting my sessions to work with the pagination. and was wondering if you might be able to help. the script works fine only problem is I cant get the query to pass onto the next page I new with sessions and am finding hard to work out the code to get the sessions work. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do it using session .. here is the way you can do it

```
//Your first part of the code

<?php 
   session_start(); // this should be in the beginning of your page

   //get the function
    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/scripts/function1.php'); 
     .    
     .. //code in between
     ...   

     if(isset($_POST['muscle'])) {

    // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.
     $clean_muscle = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['muscle']);

      //since you had a post request you can save it in session now
      // you can either save it as an array or string depending on what exactly you want to do with it.
      // if you want to do more complex work like db quering save ie in array like this
      foreach($clean_muscle as $cm){
            $_SESSION["muscle"][] = $cm;
       }

      // or if you just want to display the clean_muscle string do it this way after your implode
      $muscle = implode("','", $clean_muscle);
       $_SESSION["muscle"] = $muscle;
```

now whenever a page is loaded you just have to check if the session is set

```
   //check if session is set
  if(isset($_SESSION["muscle"]) && !empty($_SESSION["muscle"])){
      // do whatever you want to do with your variable  
   }
```

Use the same process for your equipment. Personally this whole code can be written in much better way.. but its your choice and your code.. Hope this helps.

Dins

Comment: Thank you for your help @Dinesh, I have used the $_SESSION["muscle"] = $muscle; where do add the code to check if session is set.

Comment: actually you will have to make some changes to your code cause you are actually assigning values only when you get the post request for your checkboxes.. you will have to modify your code to make these assignments either when you get the post request or when your session is set..  you can also duplicate the whole process separately by using the isset session if condition before your post and duplicate the manipulation you do inside your post condition..

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh, im new with php and was wondering how would you write the code. I know it can be written better but am not sure how to write it better. If you dont mind sharing I would be very greatful.

Comment: Hi @Dinesh , I still have haven't managed to get my code working yet, I can't seem to get the session to pass into the next page of the pagination. I was just wondering you said the code could be written much better and was wondering if you could help me out. Any help to get this code working would be much appreciated